# Can't view image via stored Uri in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

What i'm trying to do is to open a image and this image uri should be stored at my local database and then after i reopen the app the last image inserted will appear but i have a problem when i reopen the app the image not loaded from the uri in database.

My Code :

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
private ImageView imageView;
SQLiteDatabase DB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    DB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("test",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (uri VARCHAR)");

    Cursor c = DB.rawQuery("SELECT * from users",null);
    c.moveToLast();
    int UriIndex = c.getColumnIndex("uri");
    Uri image = Uri.parse(c.getString(UriIndex));

    imageView.setImageURI(image);

    Button pickImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_image_button);
    pickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });
}

private void openGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (uri) VALUES ('"+imageUri.toString()+"')");
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_PICK` will last as long as the activity does. You can use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to give temporary access to other components. But [the `Uri` will be useless once your process ends](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html), if it has a `content` scheme (and most will).

If you are expecting to have long-term access to the content identified by the `Uri`:

- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `takePersistableUriPermissions()`, as part of [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html), or
- Make a local copy of the image into your app's internal storage